# Flask problem: I get the error: Could not build url for endpoint 'FAQ_form'. Did you mean 'show_form' instead?

Tags: url, endpoint

I am collecting data using a Flask endpoint and WTF forms. WHen I try to invoke the redirect(url_for('function')) I get the error:
"werkzeug.routing.exceptions.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'FAQ_form'. Did you mean 'show_form' instead?"

The endpoints look as follows:

```
@app.route("/FAQ_form", methods=("GET", "POST"))
def show_form():
    form = CourseForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        FList["title"] = form.title.data
        FList["type"] = form.type.data
        FList["vector"] = form.vector.data
        FList["impact"] = form.impact.data

        if FList["title"] == "" or FList["type"] == "" :
            print("**** form error")


        return redirect(url_for('display_response'))
    return render_template('FAQ_form.html', form=form)`

`@app.route("/gpt_response", methods=("GET", "POST"))
def display_response(): 
    if request.method == "POST":
        if FAQ_prompt == "":
            print("****** prompt is not ready yet ******" ) 
        if FAQ_reply == "":
            print ("****** GPT reply is not ready yet ******" )     

    return render_template("gpt_response.html", result1=FAQ_prompt, result2=FAQ_reply)
```

The gpt_response.html  file looks like this:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
{% block title %}{% endblock %}

    <div> 
    <h4> The answer provided in the current SFT tool comes from OpenAI ChatGPT model's CVE FAQ data.</h4>
    <h4>     The sources the model uses include:</h4>
    <ol type="a">
    <li><b>National Vulnerability Database (NVD),</li>
    <li>The CVE Identifiers, archives of mailing list discussions,</li>
    <li>The National Institute of Standards and Technology (NIST),</li>
    <li>US-CERT, and Public reports from MITRE, FIRST, and others.</li>
    </ol>
    <h4>Future releases will contain Microsoft internal FAQ data. </h4>
    </div>
<hr>


  {% if result1 %}
    <div class="result">
    <div style="padding:10px;background-color: #EEE; margin: 20px">
        <p style="font-size: 18px">{{ result1 }}</p>
    </div>
  {% endif %}
  {% if result2 %}
  <div class="result">
    <div style="padding:10px;background-color: #EEE; margin: 20px">
        <p style="font-size: 18px">{{ result2 }}</p>    
    </div>  
  {% endif %}
```

I have looked everywhere for ideas on what the problem might be. Such as typos or incorrect function redirection target.  I checked that the html na tags are ok. THe are as follows:

```
<nav>
    <a href="{{url_for('index') }}">SFT App</a>
    <a href="{{url_for('FAQ_form') }}">FAQ Form</a>
    <a href="{{url_for('gpt_response') }}">GPT Response</a>
    <a href="{url_for('Prompts') }}"">Prompts</a>
    </nav>
```

I found that if I introduce a typo on the nav tag for the FAQ_form endpoint, the error condition seems to go away but the URL is malformed. I missed one of the double "{" before the word url and that created the situation.  Fixing the typo made the problem come back.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Everyone interested in this problem.

I found a few issues with the code I posted from which I got the error condition.  The fundamental issue was that the error refers to an incorrect understanding of the Navigation tag using hte url_for(endpoint) clause.

The proper tag should be: the function linked t the URL and not the nake of the URL itself.  In other words, the faulty tags were:

```
<nav>
    <a href="{{url_for('index') }}">SFT App</a>
    <a href="{{url_for(**'FAQ_form'**) }}">FAQ Form</a>
    <a href="{{url_for(**'gpt_response'**) }}">GPT Response</a>
    <a href="{url_for(**'Prompts'**) }}"">Prompts</a>
</nav>
```

The url_for lines were pointing to the URL used in the @app.route("endpoint") statements. They should be pointing top the functions being linked to the URL.  So they shopuld have been:

```
<nav>
        <a href="{{ url_for('index') }}">SFT</a>
        <a href="{{ url_for(**'show_form'**) }}">FAQs</a>
        <a href="{{ url_for(**'display_response'**) }}">GPT Replies</a>
        <a href="{{ url_for(**'displayFAQ'**) }}">Prompt History</a>    
        <a href="#">About</a>
   </nav>
```

This was originally OK for the first link as the name of the URL and the function were the same (i.e., "index"). However that was not true to fpr the other URLs.

I had other issues with the logic as well which I now have fixed,  but the real problem reported was the nav tags pointing to the wrong place.   Hope this might be helpful to the many people that are experimenting with Flask as a development tool and are new to Python.